# Reference for important results in linkage theory and their proofs

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Are there books or lecture notes that comprehensively introduce the (geometric/topological) theory of mechanical linkages, as well as important results and their proofs? For instance, [Kempe's Universality Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Kempe) and its proofs.

I'm not looking for the robotics side of the theory, just the "pure mathematical" aspects such as configuration spaces.

**Edit:** I have already read [Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra](http://gfalop.org/) by Erik D. Demaine. It is an excellent book but I would like to have as much background as possible so please recommend me more books, if there are any more good ones.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book *Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra* by Erik Demaine. It's commonly accepted as systematical introduction on Linkages theory from mathematical as well as algorithmic aspect aimed more at graduate students and researchers. You will find many surprising and amazing results came out easily from so simple and even direct from mathematical induction and deduction.

Addition: First time when I touched this field I read *How to Fold It* by J O'Rourke. But I think it, though readable, introduces only basic results with simple proof aimed at beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I've already read it, and I'm hoping for more (if there even is more). I'll edit that into my question.